# Objective-C library for using Google+ from iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-plus

I am new to programming on the iPhone and I want to integrate Google+ in my application. Is there any API for integrating Google+?

Comment: First hit in Google: https://developers.google.com/+/api/ Are you actually asking about an Objective-C library for interacting with this API?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, Google have an Objective-C API for many of their public services available at http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/

Comment: what is the steps for integrating objective-c client library in iphone for google+ API

Comment: @user1162034 There are now instructions available here https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/

Answer (score 0):

The Google+ iOS SDK and sample application demonstrates how you can integrate the share plugin, sign-in button, and use the Google+ history API.

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/